# Как строится ряд определений из качественных и относительных прилагательных?

Tags: однородные-неоднородные-определения

В каком порядке следуют относительные и качественные определения, составляющие неоднородный ряд? Качественные определения должны стоять перед относительными или у них свободный порядок?

Например: Ранняя суровая зимняя заря проступала сквозь мертвенную дымку (Ф.).

*Ранняя* — это *утренняя* (относительное прилагательное)?

Можно написать: "Утренняя суровая зимняя заря проступала сквозь мертвенную дымку"?  Или верно: "Суровая утренняя зимняя заря проступала сквозь мертвенную дымку"?

Почему в авторском варианте прилагательное "ранняя" стоит в начале ряда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Более невнятный пример найти трудно. Здесь определения можно тасовать как угодно. Уж такой Фадеев стилист!

Comment: Пример было нетрудно найти, он из правил Розенталя. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98  Так существуют правила составления ряда определений или их можно тасовать как угодно?

Comment: В этом примере - можно как угодно. Ранняя - видимо, не "утренняя (относительное прилагательное)", а именно ранняя, еще не разгоревшаяся, еле видная. А вообще, три неоднородных определения в ряду - почти всегда неважный стиль.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, Вы правы, ранняя - это только наступающая, еле видная. Но неоднородные определения бывают не так уж плохи, классики (Достоевский, Толстой) использовали ряд из трех определений, но только нужно чтобы они "вписывались" в предложение. По-моему, у Фадеева неплохо получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю, что есть формальные правила на этот счет. И не думаю, что при определении порядка важен разряд прилагательных (относительные или качественные). Думаю, обычно более постоянные признаки должны располагаться правее (суровая утренняя зимняя заря), но по желания автора возможна "инверсия" с целью выделения определенного признака (утренняя).

Comment: Относительные прилагательные как раз и обозначают более постоянные признаки, а инверсия должна быть оправданной. Она может перевести неоднородные отношения в однородные? Например: озорная мальчишеская улыбка - мальчишеская, озорная улыбка.

Comment: По-моему, *мальчшеская* может быть как относительным (по признаку пола), так и качественным (как тип улыбки, может быть более и менее  мальчишеской). От этого зависит постановка запятой, а не от инверсии.  Озорная мальчишеская улыбка -> Мальчишеская озорная улыбка.    Озорная, мальчишеская улыбка -> Мальчишеская, озорная улыбка.

Comment: Вызывает сомнение вариант "мальчишеская озорная улыбка".  Сначала имеем "озорную улыбку", а потом относим ее к определенному полу.  Или догадываемся о переходе относительного прилагательного в качественное: 1) свойственный мальчику - 2) легкомысленный, ребяческий.  В таких случаях не стоит строить словосочетания и ставить/не ставить запятые, ни о чем не задумываясь.